# Read columns from file

Tags: c#, text, multiple-columns

I have test.prp file that contains columns of numbers. I have added it below. I want to read  second and third columns from 3rd row to 6th row and write them into dene.txt. First column makes problem.  How can i do this with c# code? I also added my code.

file content:

```
   1
  41
   1    0.0000000000E+00    0.1000000000E+00    0.2000000000E+02    0.3901678858E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.1512811745E-04    0.9999999999E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.1000000000E+01    0.9999999999E+00   -0.1512811745E-04    0.0000000000E+00
 973    0.3925981578E-02    0.9992290362E-01    0.2000000000E+02    0.3901543748E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.3927493226E-01    0.9992284422E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.1000000000E+01    0.9992284422E+00   -0.3927493226E-01    0.0000000000E+00
 975    0.7845909576E-02    0.9969173337E-01    0.2000000000E+02    0.3901465010E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.7847417723E-01    0.9969161467E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.1000000000E+01    0.9969161467E+00   -0.7847417723E-01    0.0000000000E+00
 977    0.1175373975E-01    0.9930684570E-01    0.2000000000E+02    0.3899423873E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.1175524208E+00    0.9930666787E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00    0.1000000000E+01    0.9930666787E+00   -0.1175524208E+00    0.0000000000E+00
```

end of file

code below:

```
string oku = File.ReadAllText("test.prp");
while (oku != null)
{
    oku = oku.Remove(4, 4);

    File.WriteAllText("dene.txt", oku);
}
```

Comment: sands like you are looking for a CSV parser...

Comment: Is the file contents (test.prp) always the same (as posted) or is it variable length... e.g. is it ALWAYS 6 lines long and required data always line's 3 through 6

Comment: Numbers changes but constant length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] oku = File.ReadAllLines("Input.txt");
string[][] cells = oku.Select(x => x.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Now, you can easily get row/column you need, e.g. 3rd row, 2nd column:

```
var value = cells[2][1];
```

Remember, arrays are indexed from `0`, so 2nd column is actually under `[1]`.

btw. your current code has infinite loop...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Skip` + `Take` and `String.Split` + `String.Join`:

```
File.WriteAllLines("dene.txt", File.ReadLines("test.prp")
    .Skip(2).Take(4)
    .Select(l => string.Join(" ", l.Split().Skip(1).Take(2))));
```

I don't know the delimiter so i've assumed a space

Comment: delimiter is four space character my main problem is read these two columns and add them to x-y scattered chart by visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Why not read the file into a `string[]` array, then `string.Split` each line using a `<space>` delimiter.

```
string[] oku = File.ReadAllLines("test.prp");
foreach(string sLine in oku)
{
    string[] columns = sLine.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // Check for columns here.
    if (columns.Length >= 2)
    {
        string col2_and_3 = columns[1]+" "+colunms[2];

        // Do something with col2_and_3
   }
}
```

`string[] columns` will then have all the data for each line and you can use `columns.Length` to see if you have the extra columns you need.